# Javascript document.getElementById debugging

Tags: javascript

I am trying to practice Javascript but I am getting the 
document.getElementById(...) is null error. I am not sure why it is not working. ........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <title></title>
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body style="max-width: 960px; margin: 0px auto; background-color: green;">
        <section id="practice">

        </section>
    </body>
    <script>

    window.onload = function create() {

        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var newp = document.createElement('p');
        var pTextNode = document.createTextNode('First time creating elements on my own.');

        newDiv.className = 'contentContainer';

        newDiv.id = 'container1';

        newDiv.setAttribute('title', 'hello');


        newp.appendChild(pTextNode);
        newDiv.appendChild(newp);

        document.getElementById("#practice").appendChild(newDiv);

        }
        </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Remove the `#` sign so it's just `document.getElementById("practice")`

Comment: Remove the `#` when you call `getElementById`.

Comment: that worked thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it all correct! The issue is your syntax in the `getElementById` method. Remove the octothorpe ("#") and you'll get the results you're expecting.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

The `document.getElementById` API takes an ID parameter as a string. You don't need to use the CSS selector method of selecting IDs, so the `#` should be omitted. The line should read:

```
document.getElementById("practice").appendChild(newDiv);
```

For more information about the API, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById